# How to translate salesforce site without using custom labels?

Tags: salesforce, translation, salesforce-communities, sfdc

I need to translate a salesforce site into French language which is currently in English. I tried to use custom labels it worked but there is limit for custom labels. That's why I want to implement a different approach to translate into French language.

Comment: What do you have there that requires thousands of labels? You know you can translate fields, validation rules... Think if knowledge articles and their translations could be used to replace some static text you have there?

Comment: I've a form that really have thousands of labels and lots of picklists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large blocks of text ("terms and conditions", "privacy policy" and FAQ-like things) you could consider using Knowledge Base product.

For custom forms and picklists - are these linked to a real custom object you could translate the labels and picklists? You could just display that even if custom code would be mapping it back to your old structure, not really inserting this new dummy object.

You considered custom settings or custom metadata? Depending how structured they are could work pretty OK and it's easy to access custom settings from Visualforce. (Custom Metadata would still have to be queried but at least it doesn't count to 100 SOQLs limit)

Another option could be (ab)using Platform Cache to hold your text. Read up about CacheBuilder for example. Feels bit wasteful to use cache for static text but hey, fetch that's faster than querying some helper sobject... Maybe plan a nighly job to prime the cache every day.

Last but not least... is your Site in pure visualforce or are you usinga framework like Vue? Some of them have their own approach to translations. You may even seen it on some websites that load the page, text is written in handlebars(?) moustaches(?) like `{{PROMO_TEXT}}` and then it all gets replaced when JS finishes loading... You'd have to look around and of course it'd mean moving the form rendering to JS side, mobile-friendly, no more `<apex:inputText>`.

Comment: What about translation workbench or export/import translation for site (this option is available in site builder under language section). Do you have any idea about that like how we can implement?. I've exported the en_us.xml but didn't find my components labels there to put the translations.

Comment: You need to be precise! Nobody I know refers to Digital Experiences (formerly known as (Customer) Community or (Customer) Portal) as "Sites". "Sites" = Visualforce Sites! not the drag&drop ones. You can use the xml file to translate, yes - but first you'd have to create bunch of public parameters for all your custom components, pass texts/labels to them from the drag&drop editor... and then you'd export the xml, provide translations and then it could work. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_multilingual_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: "create bunch of public parameters for all your custom components".  So I need to add <targetConfig> <Proprty in js-meta.xml ?

Comment: If the component is LWC yes. You probably already have `<target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>` but now need whole bunch of properties added to LWC, mark them as `@api` and edit in XML to make them visible to admin. And then admin can pass what they need, different values for different languages. Either in the layout editor or in that translation export

Comment: Thanks @eyescream, it worked. I only have one final question here - In order to change the language on community, I'm providing the language selector/picker on top right corner. Can't we do that automatically using the user's locale?

Comment: It's been a while since I played with translated community, sorry. I'd think it'd support the right language out of the box after they log in? You might try asking at dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, more admins over there

Comment: Thanks a lot @eyescream. Yes, the community will be translated as soon as user login into the site based on their locale. It's working as expected.

Comment: what's your login page, custom component/visualforce? you could pass `?lang=fr_FR`, `lang=fr_CA` or something in the url to the login? vf pages have `apex:page language="fr"` you could use for overrides... Try what you can read from getHeaders, there might be preferred language (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_getHeaders.htm). aura I'm not sure, you could use `{init!}` to check user's preferred language in the browser, headers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n

Comment: It is default registration page i.e. CommunitiesSelfRegUi page.